# Java Regular Expression with string utf8

Tags: java, regex, utf-8

I have 2 strings:

String 1 from txt file, open with BufferedReader use encoding "UTF-8":

```
Tân_Dậu 1921 – Kỉ_Mão 1999
```

String 2 is my type in:

```
Tân_Dậu 1921 - Kỉ_Mão 1999
```

and my string Pattern:

```
[(]?([A-ZTĐẤ][a-záââậầấẹịỉìíợnọúùửỵýỷ]+[_][A-ZDĐẤ][a-záậãâậầấẹuịìíợọúùửỵýỷ]+)?[ ]?((\\d{4})|([?]))[ ]?[-][ ]?(([A-ZĐKẤ][a-záâỉoậầấẹịỉìíợọúùửỵýỷ]+[_][A-ZĐẤ][a-záãâậầấãẹịìíợọúùửỵýỷ]+))?[ ]?(\\d{4}|\\d{2}[)])[ ]?[)]?
```

I use:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(test.trim());
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println("-->"+m.group());
}
```

With 'test' is string 1 and 2 . But only string 2 matched.
What problem and how to slove it ? thanks for help.

Comment: Please read the formatting help - write with Markdown instead of adding HTML all over the place, and for a block of code, just indent it by 4 characters. It'll make the post easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `-`. You seem to have two versions of them. Changing your expression to this: `[(]?([A-ZTĐẤ][a-záââậầấẹịỉìíợnọúùửỵýỷ]+[_][A-ZDĐẤ][a-záậãâậầấẹuịìíợọúùửỵýỷ]+)?[ ]?((\\d{4})|([?]))[ ]?[-–][ ]?(([A-ZĐKẤ][a-záâỉoậầấẹịỉìíợọúùửỵýỷ]+[_][A-ZĐẤ][a-záãâậầấãẹịìíợọúùửỵýỷ]+))?[ ]?(\\d{4}|\\d{2}[)])[ ]?[)]?` should do the trick (example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/sW4fE1/1)).

Notice how `[-]` has been changed to `[-–]`.

Comment: thanks for help,but when i try get hexadecimal value of 2 string,it not equals, i think problem is encoding when read file text

Comment: @ThanhNguyen: The strings are different, thus their hexadecimal value will not match. What you would need to do, in that case, would be to replace `-` with `–`. If you do that, you can also use the same expression without the change I recommended.